# Bash/Shell-Move all files from subdirectories into target directory?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, move

How do I bash a command or a shell script to move all the files from the subdirectories to one target directory in Linux?

Comment: i've tried both thiton and john's solution. bother worked well. I like the oldschool idea of piping out my find onto xargs and then mv it. =). the `-exec mv {}` works equally well

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using GNU mv, the `-t` option (target directory) is pretty useful:

```
find sourcedir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 mv -t target
```

`man mv` gives more details.

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this:

```
find sourcedir -type f -exec mv {} targetdir \;
```